# blenderguru donut tutorial solidify messed up?

Tags: solidify-modifier

i forgot to press apply for solidify...which i did finally but after sculpting...this is the result.Anyway to fix it ?or start over ?

only this part looks mangled.

[image]

Comment: lol, it seems hard to fix this   ;)

Comment: That's why I used to save an interim version at the end of each lesson when following tutorials! :^)